# How should I change to svn protocol instead of http

Tags: svn

My current path of svn server is

http://file.com/repo/testproj

but I want use svn protocol instead of http

svn://file/repo/test to do a SVN sync

what I need to do.

Please help.

i have tried with following command: **svn switch --relocate http://file.com/repo/testproj  svn://file.com/repo/testproj** 
but it is giving error: 
**svn: '.' is not a working copy**

Answer (score 2):

You are probably serving the files via HTTP server, like Apache or something. You need to stop doing that and serve using `svnserve` server. This will react to `svn://` or `svn+ssh://` protocol.

Basically, as doc says,

> The easiest option is to run svnserve as a standalone “daemon” process. Use the `-d` option
> for this:
>
> `$ svnserve -d`
> `$ # svnserve is now running, listening on port 3690`
>
> When running svnserve in daemon mode, you can use the `--listen-port` and `--listen-host` options to customize the exact port and hostname to “bind” to.
>
> Once we successfully start svnserve as explained previously, it makes every repository on your system available to the network. A client needs to specify an absolute path in the repository URL. For example, if a repository is located at `/var/svn/project1`, a client would reach it via `svn://host.example.com/var/svn/project1`. To increase security, you can pass the `-r` option to svnserve, which restricts it to exporting only repositories below that path. For example:
>
> `$ svnserve -d -r /var/svn...`
>
> Using the -r option effectively modifies the location that the program treats as the root of the remote filesystem space. Clients then use URLs that have that path portion removed from them, leaving much shorter (and much less revealing) URLs:
>
> `$ svn checkout svn://host.example.com/project1`

Go through this manual: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html